# Ubuntu 12.04 won't recognize hp printer on usb

Tags: 12.04, usb, printing

I've installed 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on a computer that's over 10 years old (that's why I figured I'll install older version of Ubuntu, not sure if that was the right thing to do though), and now I need to make it work with HP LaserJet Proffesional M1212nf MFP. I've succesfully installed HPLIP on this machine so the driver should not be an issue, but the driver can't find the connected device. I tried connecting it to another machine running Windows and it worked alright, so the cable and printer are both fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How did you install hplip? Which version is it?

Comment: I tried installing hplip through repository and by downloading run file from hp's website and I got the most recent one in both cases. In both cases it behaved identically.

Comment: A bit late for this, but just for the reference I suppose I should say that I got this set up to work by connecting the printer to the router directly. hplip had no issues recognizing device connected to the network, unlike with one connected directly through USB connection. It's more of a workaround than a solution though.

Comment: If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).